# Enable CORS - Node.js + React/Redux + Axios deployed on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, redux, axios

I'm new to React, please keep this in mind.
For learning purposes I have built a simple React + Redux application that fetches data from an external API in JSON format.

Everything works fine if I manually enable CORS in Chrome (via extension).

Now, I deployed the application to Heroku and I need to permanently enable CORS to be able to access the API.
Apparently this is more complicated then I thought!

Here'my code:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);

console.log("server started");
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from "redux-promise";
import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

**src/actions/index.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_KEY = "********************************";
export const SEARCH_URL = `https://food2fork.com/api/search?key=${API_KEY}`;
export const FETCH_RECIPES = "FETCH_RECIPES";

export function fetchRecipes(searchTerm) {
    const url = `${SEARCH_URL}&q=${searchTerm}`;
    const request = axios.get(url);

    return {
        type: FETCH_RECIPES,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error returned by Chrome is: 

Failed to load https://food2fork.com/api/search?key=***********************************&q=pasta: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://my-heroku-random-domain.herokuapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable cors on server side, where you make the request, it is not possible to override cors settings from client, with few exceptions.

Comment: What do you mean? I have enabled CORS on my express server using npm cors.
And anyway the request is made by axios, which I believe runs in the client-side

Comment: You are correct, axios run on the client side, but CORS rules are only server-side settings. How do you enable CORS on express ?

Comment: "food2fork.com" is served from your Express server ?

Comment: food2fork.com is served by a third party company. Do you mean that I should use my express server as a relay? Isn't there a better way?

Comment: I assume the CORS issue is related with food2fork.com, I'm wrong ?

Comment: Well, not really, since I started coding with React I have always encountered this problem. Also with other external APIs.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: (change your app.use(CORS()) to this)

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

   // Website you wish to allow to connect
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

   // Request methods you wish to allow
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

   // Request headers you wish to allow
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

   // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
   // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

   // Pass to next layer of middleware
   next();
});
```

Comment: Hi, I think I have already tried to do that. I will try again in a few minutes. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: I have just tried and it returns the same error.
Failed to load https://food2fork.com/api/search?key=*********************************&q=lasagne: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://my-heroku-domain.herokuapp.com' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: U can trying reinstall devDependencies

Comment: The app is deployed on Heroku, devDependencies are not installed.
And by the way, I only have these stuff:
"devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },